# solr stopwords with german umlauts not working

Tags: encoding, solr, filter, lucene

Good mornin!
I have an issue with the stopword-filter in solr. I use that filter only on query. All stopwords were ignored as that tells me the filter works fine, ..except words with characters like ä,ö,or ü. 
Here my schema.xml:

```
 .....
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" tokenizerFactory="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <!--<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>-->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="25"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.HunspellStemFilterFactory" dictionary="vkf_de_DE.dic" affix="vkf_de_DE.aff" ignoreCase="true" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
 .....
```

analyzing a query phrase like e.g. "zelt für messe" in solr admin does exclude the word "für" correctly. But all requests via our websearch causes solr to get no results while using a stopword containing "ü","ä", or "ö".

stopwords.txt is correctly UTF-8 encoded.

By the way, we handle the requests to/from solr by a node-api server. Maybe the node server doesn´t use the correct encoding? But all other requests e.g. searching for words with ö,ä,or ü not containing in stopword list are reaching the solr-server correctly.

Any ideas? Thank you

---

**I got the solution:**

In one field-type, where I used the StopFilterFactory as well, there was also a charFilter which replaces all illegal characters for that field by a regular expression.
But special characters like ä,ö,ü hadn´t been considered.

Changing the regex-pattern from "([^a-z0-9])" to "([^a-z0-9öäü])" solved my problem.

```
    <fieldType name="product_number" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      ....
      <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-z0-9öäü])" replacement=""/>
      ....
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: If everything works find in Solr admin, so problem is definetely not with Solr.

Comment: Hm, yes but as I tested executing the query directly in the solr admin (debug mode), I see that the word "für" didnt reach the queryfields correctly.  here the part from the debug: "DisjunctionMaxQuery((productNumber:fr^84.0 | variantProductNumbers:fr^80.0 | alternativeProductNumbers:fr^85.0))"

Comment: Could you try this one more time, while disabling solr.HunspellStemFilterFactory, probably stemming ruins your query.

Comment: Post the solution as answer so that it can be marked as answered